# minimal code for multiple buttons de-bouncing

Tags: debounce

i have 4 buttons attached to 4 pins configured as inputs with internal pull-up activated...

is this function sufficient to get a debounced state of the pressed button?

```
byte buttonPressed(){
  byte btn = 0;
  if (digitalRead(30)==LOW) btn = 1; else
  if (digitalRead(9)==LOW) btn = 2; else
  if (digitalRead(31)==LOW) btn = 3; else
  if (digitalRead(8)==LOW) btn = 4;
  delay(20);
  return btn;
}
```

any strictly necessary improvements are welcome...

Comment: i write the code a-la-va-vite, thanks Edgar.

Comment: Currently there is no debouncing present in your code. The delay is completely useless.

Comment: Oops! I deleted my previous comment, which was wrong: I didn't notice your `else`s due to your very unconventional indent style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code should work as the most basic debouncing, although the
debouncing time may be a little bit short. Note however that, in many
instances, one would like to have a little more that the most basic. One
may also want:

- *deglitching*: when the button is held down, your hand may make the
  contacts move a little bit, making spikes in the reading that are not
  associated with a real change in the button position; you don't want
  those spikes to read as "released and pressed again"
- *edge detection*: many times you are more interested in the button
  press event than in knowing whether the button is down or up; this can
  be handled by another function, but it can be convenient to integrate
  it with the debouncing
- *non blocking operation*: your program may have better things to do
  than wasting CPU cycles inside `delay()`.

Those are the reasons most debouncing codes are significantly more
complex. But it's often worth it.

---

**Edit 1**: In view of the comments, some clarification seems to be
needed. There are two kinds of glitches a mechanical button can
experience:

1. when the button is mechanically changing position, i.e. it is being
   depressed or released; this is called a *bounce*
2. when the button is being held down, especially if the pressure on the
   button is low and the finger applying that pressure is somewhat
   shaky.

Most debouncing libraries you can find actually address both kinds of
glitches. Thus, they do *more* than just debouncing, they do what I
called “deglitching”. The previous answers implicitly assume that a
proper debouncing code *must* address both kinds.

The code posted in the question only addresses the first kind of
glitches, i.e. the *bounces* in the strict sense. That's why I wrote
that it does the “most basic debouncing”. It is however susceptible to
the second kind of glitches. So yes, with this code glitches can persist
even after debouncing.

**Edit 2**: As an example, consider the [Bounce 2](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2) library. It
provides edge detection, non blocking operation and, in the default
configuration, full deglitching. However, [it can be configured to use
an alternative debounce algorithm](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2/wiki#debounce-algorithms) called “Lock-out
interval”, which is more responsive but does not protect against the
“type 2” glitches mentioned above: it “does not cancel noise”, as the
documentation puts it.

Comment: is there any relation between deglitching and debouncing?...

Comment: @moyoumos: A bounce is just a specific kind of glitch that happens while the button is being depressed or released. If you do deglitching, e.g. by waiting until a level is stable, you are also debouncing. The converse is not true: the code you posted removes bounces but it does not properly clean glitches that happen while the button is held down.

Comment: according to what you say glitchs can exist or persist even after debouncing!!!

Comment: @moyoumos: Yes, see amended answer.

Comment: i think that any debouncing algorithm based on a time interval can't do de-glitching since bounces (or glitchs) persist after this time interval!!! am i wrong?

Comment: @moyoumos: Time-based deglitching is based on the premise that if the button has been giving a consistent reading throughout a given time interval, then that reading is not a glitch (glitches are short).

Answer (score 0):

No. Actually it just checks each button one by one. In addition only the last button is checked since it overwrites the btn variable.

The simplest way to use debouncing button 1 is:

```
byte buttonPressed()
{
    byte btn = 0;

    byte btn1Before = digitalRead(30);
    delay(50); // Wait 50 ms, or 100 depending on your debouncing time
    byte btn1After = digitalRead(30);

    if ((btn1Before == LOW) && (btn1After == LOW))
    {
        btn = 1;
    }
}
```

You have to do similar as the others. You can use only one delay (just add 4 before and after variables and check them.

```
byte buttonPressed()
{
    byte btn = 0;

    byte btn1Before = digitalRead(30);
    byte btn2Before = digitalRead( 9);
    byte btn3Before = digitalRead(31);
    byte btn4Before = digitalRead( 8);

    delay(50); // Wait 50 ms, or 100 depending on your debouncing time

    byte btn1After = digitalRead(30);
    byte btn2After = digitalRead( 9);
    byte btn3After = digitalRead(31);
    byte btn4After = digitalRead( 8);

    if ((btn1Before == LOW) && (btn1After == LOW))
    {
       btn = 1;
    } 
    else if ((btn2Before == LOW) && (btn2After == LOW))
    {
       btn = 2;
    } 
    else if ((btn3Before == LOW) && (btn3After == LOW))
    {
       btn = 3;
    } 
    else if ((btn4Before == LOW) && (btn4After == LOW))
    {
       btn = 4;
    } 

    return btn;
}
```

Note that this way the program will be unresponsive for 50 ms. If you do not want this, you have to use millis, but this makes it more complex. Check the debouncing example on the Arduino site.

Comment: why check the before and after state of the button?...

Comment: By checking that the state again after the debounce time (I chose 50 ms). If the debouncing is finished, it will show twice LOW.

Comment: i think that if the hardware detects the first LOW it's because the button is Pressed, then a delay (20 or 50ms..) is sufficient to ignore all bounces!!...

Comment: I wanted to stick to the original program. If no interrupts are used, this way the priority can be changed by software.

Answer (score 0):

No - simply `delay()`ing after reading the button doesn't tell you whether the button is still bouncing or, more importantly, what its final state is. Debouncing requires you to know that the button

- changed state;
- has stopped changing state;
- what state it has settled into.

You'll need to notice the current state doesn't match the last debounced state you saw; then either test it frequently until it doesn't change state again for some number of tests, or simply wait the known maximum time it takes to settle; then read, store, and return the final state.

Answer (score 0):

While @MichelKeijzers answer is a nice solution for simple querying in the main loop. This is not practicable for interrupts. Interrupts can block the entire MCU and interrupting an interrupt routinte can cause serious problems.

Depending on your requirements I'd suggest to take a look at using [capacitors and resistors for debouncing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66764/how-does-the-capacitor-in-a-debouncing-circuit-work#66767). With that you achieve simpler code and no need for dealing with hardware issues in software. Of course at the expense of additional parts in your hardware setup.

If your MCU for example is using a pin as interrupt, that interrupt would be called only once as opposed to bouncing one.