# Why are commands executing on their own?

Tags: arduino-uno

This is the program I have used. It's working fine. But I don't known why sometimes it operates on its own. It is used to control a welding machine (Arduino is isolated from earthing). When there is a little vibration the code executes a command. This is the code:

```
int a = 9;  //right actuator forward relay 1
int b = 12; //right actuator reverse relay 2 (orange 10)
int c = 10; //left actuator forward relay 4
int d = 11; //left actuator reverse relay 3
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
const int stepPin = 8; // HIGH =DOWN; LOW == UP
const int dirPin = 7;

void setup() {
  pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(6, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("press the foot swtich"); // Serial Monitor for Debugging
}

void loop() {
  int Val = digitalRead(5); //   Actuator 1 Clamping
  int ValR = digitalRead(6);//   Actuator 2 Clamping
  int ValS = digitalRead(4);//Stepper Motor anticlockwise
  int ValM = digitalRead(2);//Stepper Motor Clockwise
  if (Val == LOW && x == 0  ) {
    Serial.print("Val000=");
    Serial.println(Val);
    digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
    delay(1750);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    x = 1;
    Val = digitalRead(5);
    Serial.println("fwd");
    Serial.print("Val=");
    Serial.println(Val);
    delay(500);
  }
  if (Val == LOW && x == 1  ) {
    digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    x = 0;
    Val = digitalRead(5);
    Serial.println("fwd");
    y = 0;
    Serial.print("Val=");
    Serial.println(Val);
    delay(500);
  }
  if (ValR == LOW && y == 0 ) {
    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
    delay(1350);
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);
    y = 1;
    ValR = digitalRead(6);
    Serial.println("fwd");
    Serial.print("Val=");
    Serial.println(Val);
    delay(500);
  }
  if (ValR == LOW && y == 1 ) {
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    delay(1200);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    y = 0;
    ValR = digitalRead(6);
    Serial.println("fwd");
    Serial.print("Val=");
    Serial.println(Val);
    delay(500);
  }
  if (ValS == HIGH) {
    Serial.println(Val);
    Serial.println("up");
    digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
    // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
    // Makes 100 pulses for making half cycle rotation
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(1000);
      digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(1000);
    }
    // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
    // Makes 200 pulses for making one full cycle rotation
  }
  if (ValM == LOW) {
    Serial.println("down");
    Serial.println(ValR);
    digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
    // Makes 200 pulses for making one full cycle rotation
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(1000);
      digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(1000);
    }
    // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
    // Makes 200 pulses for making one full cycle rotation
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. By “it operates on its own” do you mean it acts as if the buttons are pressed, including printing the debugging output? 2. The internal pullups enabled by `INPUT_PULLUP` are quite weak (around 30 kΩ). In a noisy environment, you way want to use stronger external pullups (i.e. lower resistance).

Comment: yes its act like the button is pressed, on serial debugging also and the machine runs too. Can debouncing solve if yes how can I add it?

Comment: Debouncing may help [if it does also deglitching](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/53007). But it is probably safer to have a clean signal to start with. Thus I would try the weak pullup first. How much distance is there between the buttons and the Arduino board?

Comment: What exactly is happening? What messages are you seeing on the serial monitor? Could it be loose wires or wires touching? More information will help us help you.

Comment: anyone one of the if() loop starts randomly. There is a relay which used to switch on the welding gun.. it is not controlled by arduino it is independent ... but whenever the relay activates, the arduino execute a if statement.... no wires are loose

Comment: Are 10k resistor enough for stronger signals?

Comment: I would go straight to 1 kΩ. Also, if your buttons are more than, say, 10 cm from the Arduino board, I would wire them with a twisted pair (signal and ground on the same pair) in order to prevent inductive pick-up.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Please don't answer in comments. This totally goes against the Stack Exchange model. **Make an answer**.

Comment: Comments under questions are for seeking clarification of the question. They are **not for making mini-answers**.

Comment: Can you give details of your circuit hardware, in terms of whether wiring is soldered or breadboard/push fit together.  If you had a loose connection that would be susceptible to vibrations.

Comment: SOLDERED.  there is strong electro magnetic feilg by the welding  gun relay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to write a proper answer...

According to your description, it looks like you are victim of inductive
noise pickup. The circuit [MCU → Arduino ground pin → foot pedal →
Arduino digital input pin → MCU] is a loop that can pick up magnetic
flux. If this flux varies, either because the magnetic field varies
(ambient electromagnetic noise) or because the geometry of the circuit
changes (you move the wires), this will induce an electromagnetic force
that can make your Arduino read `LOW` even when the button is not
pressed.

There are two things you can try to overcome this effect:

1. Replace the weak internal pullup of the Arduino by a much stronger
   external pullup. Something around 1 kΩ should make it quite hard for
   the noise to pull the signal low.
2. Connect the pedal to the Arduino board using a twisted pair of wires,
   like the ones found in telephone or network cables. This kind of
   cable does a good job at minimizing inductive pickup.

Comment: I will try with 1k resistor. The Button is actually a foot switch at a distance of 10 feet from arduino

Comment: The problem is same with 1K resistor too.. the wires are shielded properly

Comment: It only happens when welding gun relay is activated

Comment: The welding gun may be a source of huge electromagnetic noise.

Comment: what can i do now?